# How can i check “whether two state space are equivalent" in SMT Solver like z3

Tags: z3, smt, model-checking, state-space

I'm a SMT Beginner. I am confused how to check “whether two state space are equivalent"  and encoding this problem in SMT.

For example, I have a register called "reg". Then, I write "dataIn1" and "dataIn2" to the "reg" in sequence. as follows .

```
reg = BitVec('reg',1)
dataIn1 = BitVec('dataIn1',1)
dataIn2 = BitVec('dataIn2',1)

state_space_1 = reg==dataIn1
state_space_2 = reg==dataIn2
```

Obviously, both state_space_1 and state_space_2 represent that "reg" can be either 0 or 1. So, state_space_1 and state_space_2 are equivalent.

However, how can I check “whether state_space_1 and state_space_2 are equivalent" and encoding this problem in SMT solver like z3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion that `Obviously... state_space_1 and state_space_2 are equivalent` isn't true. Note that you have three separate variables here: `reg`, `dataIn1` and `dataIn2`. And `state_space_1` represents the part of the space where `reg` equals `dataIn1`, and `state_space_2` represents the part of the space where `reg` equals `dataIn2`. There's no reason to expect these two spaces to be the same.

Here's some more detail. In a typical SAT/SMT query, you ask the question "is there a satisfying model for the constraints I've asserted?" So, to check equivalence, one asks if two expressions can differ. That is, ask if `X != Y` can be satisfied. If the solver can find a model for this, then you know they are not equal, and the model represents how they differ. If the solver says `unsat`, then you know that `X = Y` must hold, i.e., they represent the exact same state-space.

Based on this your example would be coded as:

```py
from z3 import *

reg     = BitVec('reg', 1)
dataIn1 = BitVec('dataIn1', 1)
dataIn2 = BitVec('dataIn2', 1)

state_space_1 = reg == dataIn1
state_space_2 = reg == dataIn2

s = Solver()
s.add(Not(state_space_1 == state_space_2))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[dataIn2 = 1, dataIn1 = 0, reg = 0]
```

So, we conclude that `state_space_1` and `state_space_2` do *not* represent the same state-space. They differ when `dataIn1` is `0`, `dataIn2` is `1`, and `reg` is `0`.

If you are new to SMT solving, you might want to skim through Yurichev's SAT/SMT by example document (https://sat-smt.codes/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf), which should give you a good overview of the techniques involved from an end-user perspective.

To find out more regarding z3 programming, [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html) is an excellent resource.